# Where is the SQL connection string and sql query text stored in Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have an excel with some SQL data loaded using power query.

I wonder whether the connection string and SQL query are included in Excel file. It would make it unsafe to share.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove data sources from menu Data->Get Data->Launch Power Query Editor and there add database server, query, etc.
[image]

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't answer my question. I know how to connect excel to database. I wonder, whether the sensitive connection info in embedded in the excel file